# Suppress rails server output

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Running the rails server with `rails s` results in a huge amount of text being outputted to the screen, as it appears to be logging at the verbose `:info` level. When I'm debugging, sometimes I just to print a few variables to screen via awesome_print, and don't want to sift through the text.

**So is there a config setting in the developlment environment file I can set to completely supress the output, (apart from the output from my `ap` calls)?**

Comment: you **could** just detach the server from the console using `rails s --detach`

Answer (score 1):

You can silence the assets and just get the important information for developing, just add a file in your initializers, like **config/initializers/silent_assets.rb** with the following code

```
if Rails.env.development?

  Rails.application.assets.logger = Logger.new('/dev/null')

  Rails::Rack::Logger.class_eval do
    def call_with_quiet_assets(env)
      previous_level = Rails.logger.level
      Rails.logger.level = Logger::ERROR if env['PATH_INFO'] =~ %r{^/assets/}
      call_without_quiet_assets(env)
    ensure
      Rails.logger.level = previous_level
    end
    alias_method_chain :call, :quiet_assets
  end

end
```

Comment: where do you define `call_without_quiet_assets`?

Comment: Ah, it's created by `alias_method_chain`

Answer (score 0):

You can control what gets logged in development, by customizing your `config/environments/development.rb` file.

[Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) you can find documentation on the various options.

You might want to set:

1. `config.log_level`
2. `config.assets.debug` (controls assets compilation and, as a side effect, shuts down assets compilation messages)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to edit the file **config/environments/development.rb**, and set the log level to error:

```
config.log_level = :error
```

Then just print with awesome_print

```
ap {a: 1, b: 2}
```

If you start the server from the console like

```
script/rails s
```

In that console you will see just the output of awesome_print

Comment: So `script/rails s` instead of `rails s`? What's the significance of this?

Comment: btw do you mean `bin/rails s` ? :)

Comment: just start the server from the console, like running **rails server**

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers answer the question.

Use

```
config.logger = Logger.new('log/development.log')
```